# Difference between thread priorities

Tags: java, multithreading

What does thread priority means? will a thread with `MAX_PRIORITY` completes its execution before a thread which has `MIN_PRIORITY`? Or a `MAX_PRIORITY` thread will be given more execution time then `MIN_PRIORITY` thread? or any thing else?

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for Thread only says this, "Threads with higher priority are executed in preference to threads with lower priority."  That can mean different things depending on what JVM you are running and, more likely, on what operating system you are running.

In the simplest interpretation of "priority", as implemented by some real-time, embedded operating systems; a thread with a lower priority will *never* get to run when a higher priority thread is waiting to run.  The lower priority thread will be immediately preempted by whatever event caused the higher priority thread to become runnable.  That kind of absolute priority is easy to implement, but it puts a burden on the programmer to correctly assign priorities to all of the different threads of *all* of the different processes running in the box.  That is why you usually don't see it outside of embedded systems.

Most general-purpose operating systems assume that not all processes are designed to cooperate with one another.  They try to be fair, giving an equal share to each thread that wants CPU time.  Usually that is accomplished by continually adjusting the thread's true priorities according to some formula that accounts for how much CPU different threads have wanted in the recent past, and how much each got.  There usually is some kind of a weighting factor, to let a programmer say that this thread should get a larger "share" than that thread.  (e.g., the "nice" value on a Unix-like system.)

Because any practical JVM must rely on the OS to provide thread scheduling, and because there are so many different ways to interpret"priority"; Java does not attempt to dictate what "priority" really means.